# How to browse docker container in the PyCharm IDE?

Tags: docker, pycharm

Is there a feature in PyCharm to browse a docker container?
Something similar to "Browse remote Host", but I want to browse a docker container to be able to edit files inside a container. What I currently do is
"`docker exec -ti <container> bash`", and then `nano filename`. This way I can edit files using nano. What I try to achieve is to be able to edit container files inside PyCharm IDE.

**Update:**

Let's assume we are running nginx docker image and want to share a volume with /etc/nginx of the running container. Please advise what should I add after `-v` when firing the `docker run` command.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such feature. An alternative is to mount the files you want to change into the container during `docker run -v $(pwd):/mnt ...`. By doing this you can edit the mounted files from your IDE.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to do this? I want to achieve something similar.

Comment: @aymusbond nope

Answer (score 1):

I don't know pycharm enough to know if such feature is performed but you will have a problem to look for such information unless you creates a volume between the container and the host.

To enable this you can syncronize some local directory of you host docker machine with the container by adding

```
-v /HOST_DIRECTORY/PATH:/CONTAINER/DORECTORY/PATH
# TO ENABLE THE CURRENT DIRECTORY:
-v $(pwd):/PATH
```

[Docker oficial Reference:](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-a-container)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wanted to be able to do something similar and though I couldn't find a way to browse the docker container from PyCharm while I'm still inside the docker, I still found a way with which I can do something similar outside the container.

The way to do this is to copy the container files/folders to your local filesystem. Now when these files are present in your local machine you can follow your typical procedures to open them and edit them in PyCharm IDE.

Once the changes are made and saved, again copy these files to the container (which will replace the old files with the new ones). And you are done!

At least for my purposes, this works well. I am still new to Docker so I have no idea if this might break something.

Now the commands to do this are (taken from the Docker docs)-

To copy from the container to the local system:

```
$ docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
```

To copy back the edited files from the local system to the container:

```
$ docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH
```

More information can be found in the official [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/#:%7E:text=The%20docker%20cp%20utility%20copies,from%20STDIN%20or%20to%20STDOUT%20.).